# I am unable to run application via usb debugging .Earlier it was working fine

Tags: android

Usb debugging in my mobile has stopped working. The application is not installing via USB.Earlier It was working fine.I am attaching logs. Please help me to find out error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.(SupportActivity.java:96)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:28)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:34)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.(FragmentActivity.java:67)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
>                                                                                     at com.kpfactors_mbl.bizfactors.Login.(Login.java:68)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library:
>   reloc_library[1307]:  1842 cannot locate '__isnanf'...at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.ProfilerService.(ProfilerService.java:41)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.(SupportActivity.java:96) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:28) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:34) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.(FragmentActivity.java:67) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.(AppCompatActivity.java:61) 
>                                                                                     at com.kpfactors_mbl.bizfactors.Login.(Login.java:68) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
>                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Insert some critical code block if you want fast answer from somebody ! No just error log .

Comment: Code is fine..I did not make any changes in code. This is working on one device. Even if i build apk than install..it is working

Comment: Ok , did you try to check device setting like Developer -> USB debugging  , uninstall your app and install again etc...

Comment: I have already tried that..not worked